# Serialization: Change the name of the root node without changing the class name

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization, ixmlserializable

**Goal**

Take a class named "Item" and output its serialized XML as:

```
<Template><!--some properties --></Template>
```

**Problem**

The root node is derived off the class name that is implementing IXmlSerializable.

```
    // By the time I get here 'writer' already has a root node
    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("Template");
         // write out the properties
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }
```

So I wind up with XML that looks like

```
<Item><Template><!-- some properties --></Template></Item>
```

**Question**

Is there an attribute, a property I can override, or anything to get my desired effect (aside from changing the class name)?

Thanks!

**Resolution thanks to Frederik!**

Since the question is sort of answered in my comment of @Frederik Gheysels answer, I thought I would put it here so it doesn't get buried.

Just add an XmlRoot attribute to your class and this will change the output xml of the root node.

Example:

```
[XmlRoot("Template")]
public class Item : IXmlSerializable
{
   //Item's properties
}
```

Comment: Please show the code that does the serialization and show where the Item class is located. Is it a member of some other class?

Comment: I think you want the XML Type attribute


http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z(VS.71).aspx

Comment: @John Saunders: Item is not a member of another class. I was using the built in .Net XmlSerializer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

check the [XmlRootAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlrootattribute.aspx) class.

Comment: Awesome. Your answer helped me find the `XmlRoot` attribute. By adding `[XmlRoot("Template")]` above my class declaration `public class Item : IXmlSerializable`. I was able to get the desired effect.